# Match after space or everything without space

Tags: regex, servicenow

I would like to have a regex to match string after space or without space.
here's example of input:

```
Singapore NET-AP-1

Thailand Bangkok RT-SW-2b

WIN-OS-0
```

Output should be like this:

```
NET-AP-1

RT-SW-2b

WIN-OS-0
```

I tried `.*\s(.*)` and this is only good for first 2 but not the last without space.

Comment: Specify in which language you want to do this and edit the tag accordingly. space is not a valid tag.!!

Comment: Simply use `.*\s(.*)|(.*)`

Comment: If the pattern you're trying to match is always in that form, you could also use `\w+-\w+-\w+`

Comment: I would use `(?:.+ )?(.+)`

Comment: '(?:.+ )?(.+)' is what I am looking for. It works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> (\w+-)+\w+

if your input line always like

> NET-AP-1 then

**above regex will help.**